# MATLAB Break line in code that contains filepath

Tags: matlab, filepath, line-breaks

I am getting a file with the uigetfile command. However the filepath is quite long. How can I break up the command so that it uses two lines in the code instead of one?

I tried this with the ... in the middle of the file name, but MATLAB seems to not understand what I want to do and puts out a "Unexpected MATLAB expression." error.

This is the line of code in question:

```
filename = uigetfile('C:\Users\Timos Laptop\Documents\Studium\M.Sc. Geowissenschaften\Geowissenschaftliche ' ... 
'Projektübung\Labor\B2 1 2.85-3.2 m.txt');
```

Tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surround your long string with square brackets to set up a concatenation of two `char` arrays, like so: `uigetfile(['C:\User...' ... 'Projekt...']);`. And, Timo: Überdenke einmal deine Verzeichnisstruktur, das ist ja absurd umständlich! ;-)

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you very much.

PS: Ich sollte da wirklich mal Ordnung reinbringen. Danke! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Something else to consider, building on HansHirse's answer, is to create character arrays for each of the sections of the file path and then concatenate those together when you call `uigetfile`. This is helpful if you have to use the same paths repeatedly throughout a project. For example:

```matlab
myDocuments = 'C:\Users\Timos Laptop\Documents\';
myProject = 'Studium\M.Sc. Geowissenschaften\GeowissenschaftlicheProjektübung\Labor\';
myFile = 'B2 1 2.85-3.2 m.txt';

filename = uigetfile([myDocuments myProject myFile];
```

If you are using some form of version control like git and you decide to change `myFile`, you will be able to tell immediately from a `git diff` that just `myFile` changed with this method -- otherwise you have to parse a more complicated output.

Comment: My preferred solution would be to not include the `filesep` and do a `fullfile` on each of the components, but I acknowledge that is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: I agree, `fullfile` is the best solution.

Comment: That is a really clever thing to do, thanks for your input!